# SSIS dynamic excel column header

Tags: excel, dynamic, import, header, ssis

I am having a problem using SSIS and hoped someone could help me. I am new to this Microsoft software and I was asked to import data from a Excel schedule file that features 13 weeks. So the data is displayed as followed in the Excel file:

```
Person id | Person age| School activity | Activity leader| 18-06-2012 | 25-06-2012 | ..(more weeks)

1452      | 14        | Painting        | John Smith     | 2          | 6          | ...
```

where 2 and 6 represent the amount of hours spent on the this activity per week.

Although, person id, person age, school activity and activity leader are static column header in this excel file, the weeks column header while change from file to file.

Therefore, I do not know how to import such a data file to my database because I am having mapping issues from a file to another.

I want the data placed into the database as separate rows for each of the week columns, so I am using the unpivot transform to achieve that.  What I want is to be able to import the data regardless of the column header.

Comment: Are there always the same number of columns or are there different numbers of columns per file?

Comment: Yes, there are. It is just the week columns that change.
This week I have 13 weeks starting from 18-06-2012 going up to 10-09-2012. So next week I'll have another one with the same columns but the week columns will be from 25-06-2012 up to 17-09-2012.

Comment: Is it possible for the data to be dumped as plain csv files?  The flat file importer doesn't really care what the column headers are, so if you can bring in a consistently-formatted file (13 columns, comma-separated, quoted strings, for example), you can simply skip the header row and then perform whatever manipulation you want on the data itself.

Comment: Also, can you define the schema mapping for us?  In other words, you have these columns in Excel...  What are the corresponding columns in your database/how is the data represented in the database?

Comment: The columns in the database are the following:  

Person id->Person id  
Person age->Person age  
School activity->School activity  
Activity leader->Activity leader  
18-06-2012,25-06-2012,... -> Week  
Rows below the week label -> Amount of hours  

I am planning on getting those columns with the unpivot transformation.

Comment: Sorry for the display but I'm not managing to add linebreaks...

Comment: Well, if you can get the data in csv format, this will be easy to solve.  Is it possible for you to get the data dumped that way instead of as an xls/xlsx?

Comment: Yes, I can. Thank you very much for your help and time and also thank you  Preet Sangha. Both replies were very helpful and based on your answers I managed to solved this issue. =)

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I posted it as the answer, if you wouldn't mind hitting accept on it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data can be provided as CSV, you can use a Flat File Source and then skip the header row, so long as there will always be the same number of columns with the same, predictable formatting.

You mentioned in the discussion that you would be using the unpivot transform to turn the data into individual rows, so you know how to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this problem recently. The biggest issue I found is that SSIS with Excel expects a static set of columns.

So I took the set of files and built a similar data flow for each (differing only where the columns were different). I then put a control flow with a File Enumerator to pick up all the files and make the decision based on file name as to the data flow to use.

It wasn't elegant - but it works very well.

Comment: Well, the issue is that doing so, I would have to create a data flow each time I had a new schedule file. Isn't there a way to this automatically?